# Property with custom TypeConverter is not serialized to deisgner.cs

Tags: c#, serialization, type-conversion, custom-controls, designer

I've a class defining two values as long:

```
[Serializable, TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(RangeConverter))]
public class Range : ICloneable, IEquatable<Range>, IEqualityComparer<Range>
{
    long min;
    long max;
    public long Min
    {
        get { return min; }
        set { min = value; }
    }
    //[etc....]
}
```

The `RangeConverter` is exactly identical to the .NET [SizeConverter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/SizeConverter.cs,86ceb450bb606020), except for small changes because of the change from `int` to `long`.

Then, in my custom user control I have a property:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
// I tried also this:
//[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public Range SelectedRange
{
    get { return range; }
    set { range = value;}
}
```

This property is never serialized to the designer.cs. Is there something specific I'm missing here? Sometimes I get an error from VisualStudio saying that the Rage was not converted to InstanceDescriptor. Can this problem explain the lack of serialization?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the reason. My Range class had other fields and one of this was not serializable **but** still not marked in that way. By adding the attribute `[NonSerialized]` to that field, the Range class is properly serialized to the designer.cs